# Using QueryDSL Projections.bean for Nested Classes

Tags: querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL to map my queries to my Beans using this:

```
QAmbiente qitem=new QAmbiente("x");
SQLTemplates template = new MySQLTemplates(); // SQL-dialect
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(template); 
SQLQuery query = new SQLQuery(conn, configuration);
List<Ambiente> items = query.from(qitem).list(Projections.fields(Ambiente.class, qitem.idEmpresa));
```

My problem is that i have nested classes for primary keys,  like this:

```
@EmbeddedId
protected AmbientePK ambientePK;
```

Then when i try to execute above code, an error is thrown:

```
The bean of type: br.com.fitsoft.cnfe.model.domain.Ambiente has no property called: idEmpresa
```

The problem occurs only when i put a field that is part of my primary key.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of code that works properly (say, by using a field that is not part of your primary key)?

Comment: Could you also describe what behaviour you expected? If Ambiente doesn't have a idEmpresa property, it can't be populated, like the Exception says.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
.list(Projections.bean(ItemNotaFiscal.class,
    i.aliqCofinsReal.as("aliqCofinsReal"),
    i.aliqPisPerc.as("aliqPisPerc"),
    Projections.bean(Qpk, 
            i.ambientePK.idEmpresa
    ).as("ambientePK")
));
```